# Nginx not serving files from changed document root

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare, roundcube

I seem to be having an issue with my Nginx (version 1.11.9) installation. I have set up a LEMP stack on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, and also have mail services running on it as well. I'm using the following agents :- Postfix and Dovecot.  Now the reason for setting up LEMP is to facilitate webmail using Roundcube. I have set up symbolic links within sites-enabled, deleted link to default and added site config file called roundcube. The problem I am having is the default_server document root is not loading any pages from that location, it only seems to be loading pages from the Nginx default location /usr/share/nginx/html

I have specified root to be /usr/share/nginx/roundcube but no pages load from that location. I been going over this a 3 weeks now and I'm just getting frustrated as I cant see the issue. I will list the Nginx config files I have amended.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

P.S I am using Cloudflare DNS

Thanks Rob

nginx.conf :-

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
##
# Basic Settings
##
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 10 10;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;
port_in_redirect off;
client_max_body_size 4096k;
client_body_timeout 10;
client_header_timeout 10;
send_timeout 10;
#server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
#server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/ vnd.ms-fontobject;

##
# SSL Settings
##
#ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Sitewide SSL settings
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_buffer_size 4k;

# Sitewide proxy settings
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#   listen     localhost:110;
#   protocol   pop3;
#   proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#   listen     localhost:143;
#   protocol   imap;
#   proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Sites-available config file "roundcube" contents :-

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    if ($http_cf_visitor ~ '{"scheme":"http"}') {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
 }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    if ($http_cf_visitor ~ '{"scheme":"http"}') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/roundcube;
    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex off;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-mail-example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-key-decrypted-mail-example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES    :RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;

    # Client auth via certs
#   ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/private/example.com.crt;
#   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/example.com.crt;
#   ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
#       if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~* "user@example.com") {
#           return 301 http://www.jurassicsystems.com/;
#       }
#       error_page 403 @fallback;
    }

    location ~ ^/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(config|bin|SQL|logs|temp)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/.*\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php7.1-fpm-sock;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location @fallback {
        return 301 http://www.jurassicsystems.com/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted `nginx`? Also, use `nginx -T` to test the configuration and ensure that it is reading the correct configuration files.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes I have reloaded the Nginx service everytime I have made a config change. nginx -T prints out the correct files as listed above, with the addition of the fastcgi_params config and mime.types. I also get the output "nginx.conf syntax is ok" and "nginx.conf test is successful".